# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jnetpcap/Pcap

Tags: java, linux

[image]

```
import org.jnetpcap.*;

List<PcapIf> alldevs = new ArrayList<PcapIf>(); // Will be filled with NICs  
StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder();     // For any error msgs  

int r = Pcap.findAllDevs(alldevs, errbuf);  
if (r == Pcap.NOT_OK || alldevs.isEmpty()) {  
    System.err.printf("Can't read list of devices, error is " + errbuf.toString());  
    return;  
}
```

I really don't know what I'm missing here. The file works in Eclipse, however not via the command line!

Comment: Can you show me the first couple of lines of your code?

Comment: @AlexK Updated, this is where it complains!

Comment: you need to have the full path to the jpcap jar file in the classpath, not just the directory it's in. So something like `-cp /home/karl/sslarp/lib/jpcap.jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`jnetpcap.jar`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnetpcap/files/jnetpcap/1.3/dev/) to the runtime classpath. This probably exists in the classpath in Eclipse but is not present in the current command line classpath

```
sudo java -cp /home/../lib:jnetpcap.jar:. -Djava.libary.path=... sslarp.controller.Controller
```